# issues with javascript website copy element to antoher element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having issues with this website. I want to copy a li element from the gists element to the favorites element. However, when I click on the buttons they flash on favorites but don't stay there. How can I make the element stay on favorites?

http://jsfiddle.net/a059bka3/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assignment4.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var gists; // = [];

        function getGists()
        {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if(!request)
            {
                throw 'Unable to create HttpRequest.';
            }
            var url = 'https://api.github.com/gists/public';
            //var url = 'https://api.github.com/gists/users/:smithjoe123/gists';

            request.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if(this.readyState == 4)
                {
                    //console.log(this.responseText);
                    var txt = this.responseText.trim("\"");
                    gists = JSON.parse(txt);
                    displayGists();
                }
            };
            request.open('GET', url);
            request.send();
        }

        function displayGists()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                var br1 = document.createElement("br");
                var br2 = document.createElement("br");
                var br3 = document.createElement("br");

                var button = document.createElement('button');
                button.setAttribute("gistIdButton", gists[i].id);
                button.innerHTML = 'add to favorites';
                button.onclick = function(){
                    var nodef = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("gistIdButton")).cloneNode(true);
                    console.log(this.getAttribute("gistIdButton"));
                    favoritesList.appendChild(nodef);
                }

                var gistsList = document.getElementById('gistsList');
                var node = document.createElement("LI");   
                //var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");  
                var textnode = document.createTextNode(gists[i].description);
                //textnode.setAttribute("gistId", gists[i].id);
                var textnodeAddress = document.createTextNode(gists[i].url);  
                //node.setAttribute("gistId", gists[i].id);
                node.setAttribute("id", gists[i].id);
                node.appendChild(textnode); 
                node.appendChild(br1); 
                node.appendChild(textnodeAddress); 
                node.appendChild(br2);
                node.appendChild(button);
                node.appendChild(br3); 
                gistsList.appendChild(node);

                console.log("dfdfz");
                //gists[i].description
            }

        }

        function displayFavorites()
        {
        }

        getGists();
        console.log(gists);

        //console.log(gists[0].user);
</script>

<form action="" method="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="python">Python
    <input type="checkbox" name="json">JSON
    <input type="checkbox" name="javascript">JavaScript
    <input type="checkbox" name="sql">SQL
    <br>
    <button type="button">Search</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="gists"> gists
        <br>
        <ul id="gistsList">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="favorites"> favorites
        <br>
        <ul id="favoritesList">
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be missing the `return false;` on the click event. See the following lines:

```
var nodef = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("gistIdButton")).cloneNode(true);
console.log(this.getAttribute("gistIdButton"));
favoritesList.appendChild(nodef);
return false;
```